# After enabling PayPal Express site went bonkers

Tags: magento-1.8, paypal-express

I am a 1st time user tying to set up a magento store. After enabling PayPal Express and saving changes the page went blank. Now I cant log into the admin page and the web site just shows text and links no html. www.TaberPens.com/mymagento.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Not really enough information here to help debug. But if all you have done is enable Paypal, possible causes could be cache or compiler, or something simple like that. Have you tried disabling either?

Comment: You really need to look at the log files to work out the core issue though. So in your var/log folder, then system.log file.

Comment: This page will help you debug a bit too - https://kb.magenting.com/content/22/38/en/magento-shows-blank-empty-page-how-do-i-solve-this.html

Answer (score 1):

No worry, Just one bug is there.

The styles loading from URL - http://www.taberpens.com/mymagentoskin/frontend/default/theme596/css/styles.css

It should be
-**http://www.taberpens.com/mymagento/skin/frontend/default/theme596/css/styles.css**

http://www.taberpens.com/mymagento after this one slash **/** is missing. :)

Comment: Well, i don't have 50+ reputation to post this in comment. :P